# Can a person offer Pind-Daan to his uncle , grand-uncle ,great granduncle etc?

Tags: pitru

In case someone is unmarried and dies , can his nephew and his lineage offer pind-daan to him ?

Upto what degree of relation can someone offer Pind-daan to his ancestors ?

Basically my question is -

**Can a person offer Pind-Daan to his uncle , grand-uncle ,great granduncle etc ?**

Can nephew of second degree offer Pind-daan i.e. Can son of one's cousin offer Pind-daan to him ?

Comment: there is a list of sapinda rules - ask your purohit at nearby temple